# Bezug von "wie man meinen könnte" in langem Satz

Tags: usage

Aus dem *Spiegel-Magazin*:

> Es sind keine Verrückten und Axtmörder, die in Scharen nach Syrien reisen, in einem barbarischen Krieg kämpfen wollen, der doch wenig mit ihnen zu tun hat, **wie man meinen könnte**. Es sind normale Männer, junge Muslime aus Dinslaken, Hamburg, Berlin -- scheinbar.

Worauf bezieht sich die Phrase **"wie man meinen könnte"**? Bezieht sie sich auf

> (a) Es sind keine Verrückten und Axtmörder

oder

> (b) der doch wenig mit ihnen zu tun hat

oder

> (c) Es sind keine Verrückten und Axtmörder, die in Scharen nach Syrien reisen, in einem barbarischen Krieg kämpfen wollen, der doch wenig mit ihnen zu tun hat

?

Comment: Ich hoffe, die Überschrift verbessert zu haben, aber ganz glücklich macht sie mich immer noch nicht.

Comment: Sehr schöne Frage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bei dem gegebenen Kontext würde ich auf

> (a) Es sind keine Verrückten und Axtmörder

tippen. Zusammen mit dem nächsten Satz:

> Es sind keine Verrückten, wie man meinen könnte. Es sind normale junge Männer.

Allerdings ist die gesamte Konstruktion stilistisch fragwürdig. Auch im nächsten Satz ist nicht völlig klar, worauf sich das nachgestellte *-- scheinbar* bezieht. Sind es doch keine normalen jungen Männer? Oder kommen sie etwa doch nicht aus den genannten Städten?

Comment: Echt? Ich würde es auf "..wenig zu tun hat" beziehen. Den Anfang hatte ich schon halb vergessen. Ersetz mal "wie man meinen könnte" durch "nach allem was ich weiß" oder etas ähnliches. Fühlt sich das dann auch noch so an als beziehe es sich auf den Hauptsatz?

Comment: @Emanuel Naja, das war eben mein erster Eindruck nach den beiden Sätzen. Deine Interpretation ist natürlich auch plausibel, vielleicht sogar naheliegender. In jedem Fall erzeugt diese Formulierung (vielleicht absichtlich?) Unsichertheit, was die Identität, Herkunft und Motive der beteiligten Personen betrifft.

Comment: ('vielleicht absichtlich') Haha... ich glaube da unterstellst du den Spiegel-Autoren zuviel literarisches Geschick ;)

Answer (score 1):

(b) oder (c), denn wenn (a) gemeint wäre, stände der Einschub direkt nach den "Verrückten und Axtmördern".

Comment: Sehe ich genau so, allerdings wäre der Einschub da extrem störend